# layout changes on iOS 11 navigation bar and screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I'm currently working on a new version of an app made with Objective-C and iOS 8.x

I have two issues with the layout:

- a bar with a uniform background color is displayed on top of my navigation bar, hiding half of the content of my navigationitem
- a large white bar is displayed at the bottom of the screen

The latest update of the app was with iOS 9.3, so it is related to a change in iOS 10 or 11.

The issue is observed on iphone6. Or iPhone X this issue is observed as well but there is a space above the top bar:

screenshot iPhone 6: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHLP4.png

screenshot iPhone X: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVsBt.png

I tried to set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` to `true` but it makes things worst: the top bar is still there and another large bar is added.

Comment: This looks like something added by your app. What type does the View Debugger think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 11, navigation bar height increased. This is one way to support iPhone X devices.

```
if(@available(iOS 11,*))
{
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false;
   self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
}

CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
NSLog(@"Status bar height:%f",statusBarHeight);

double CurrentDevicescreenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
NSLog(@"Current Device Height:%f",CurrentDevicescreenHeight);

if(CurrentDevicescreenHeight == 812) {

    CGFloat iPhoneXstatusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
    NSLog(@"iPhone X Device:- Status bar height:%f",iPhoneXstatusBarHeight);

    float tophight  = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"iPhone x device navigation bar height:%f",tophight);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44);

}
```